# Get the referred link id on pagebeforeshow

Tags: jquery-mobile

In jqm I have something like this

```
<li><a href="#page1" id="cats" class="loadPage">cats</a></li>
<li><a href="#page1" id="dogs" class="loadPage">dogs</a></li>
```

Page1 is a dynamic page and should load it's contents based on which link button I pressed and I use

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page1', function(event, data){
    do something here with either cats or dogs
});
```

Now how do I determine here what link what used?
I could use sessionStorage or perhaps a

```
$('.loadPage').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('id').blablabla
})
```

but it doesn't seem right to me. I'm sure the answer is there right in front of me, but I can't seem to get around it.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$('.loadPage').on('click', function(){ if($(this).attr('id') == 'cats') { do modifications on #page1; $.mobile.changePage('#page1'); } });` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UtFPn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the `id` in `#page1`'s `data` attribute on click of `loadPage`:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page0", function () {
    $(this).on("click", ".loadPage", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#page1").data("id", this.id);
    });
});
```

Then, after jQM redirects you to `#page1`, check for the stored `data` :

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page1", function () {
    alert($(this).data("id")); 
    // you can do anything with this id
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/wN2L9/

Comment: Fantastic. Just what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

compare the id:

```
if(this.id==='cats')
{
  //do something here
}
```

On a side note you can use `$(this).attr('id')` also, but its better you use pure JavaScript whenever possible.